# rails to_json incorrectly converting hash

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I think I found a bug with the to_json method in Rails.

I have generated a fresh scaffold and modified the create method to render the errors in JSON format.

The to_json method is removing the array from the returned hash.

Here is the result of a debug session.

(rdb:2) @recipe.errors
{:name=>["can't be blank"]}

(rdb:2) @recipe.errors.to_json
"{\"name\":\"can't be blank\"}"

As you can see, the array has been removed.

Has anyone else found this?

Cheers,

Tim

Comment: What does `{:name=>["can't be blank"]}.to_json` do in the Rails console?

Comment: If I try and convert @recipe.errors.to_json then it doesn't work but if I copy the exact hash that @recipe.errors produces and run to_json on that, then it works. Bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

```
irb(main):003:0> {:name=>["can't be blank"]}.to_json
=> "{"name":["can't be blank"]}"
```

I use ruby1.9.2, and I don't find the bug above.
May be the problem has been resolved:)